# PostgreSQL, JsonB from a column with multiple keys pass it into multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a column in the DB which stores data from an API but it's as the following:

| ID | jsonb column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {{"code1": "AB", "code2": "BC", "code3": "CD"}, {"code1": "DE", "code2": "EF"}} |
| 2 | {{"code1": "AB", "code2": "BC", "code3": "CD"}} |

And I want to transform it like this:

| ID | Code 1 | Code 2 | Code 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB | BC | CD |
| 1 | DE | EF |  |
| 2 | AB | BC | CD |

OR

| ID | Code 1 | Code 2 | Code 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB~DE | BC~EF | CD |
| 2 | AB | BC | CD |

Thanks for you help!

I need help on building a SQL code for above queries

Comment: Can you show us the queries you tried?

Comment: Your sample data is invalid JSON and can't be stored in a jsonb (or json) column. Are those values supposed to be JSON arrays?

Comment: @bergi I used this query: select
 id,
 jsonb_path_query(jsonb_colum, '$.code1') AS code1,
 jsonb_path_query_array(jsonb_colum, '$[*].code1') as code1 
from
 table                                         but I'm facing the following: ERROR: function jsonb_path_query_array(jsonb, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 84

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The column actually is in jsonb type

Comment: Well, `{{"code1": "AB", "code2": "BC", "code3": "CD"}}` is invalid JSON

Comment: @LuisEnriqueGardunoMorales What version of postgres are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those values are in reality JSON arrays (e.g. `[{"code1": "AB", "code2": "BC", "code3": "CD"}]`), you can use `jsonb_to_recordset()`

```
select t.id,
       r.*
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_to_recordset(t.data) as r("code1" text, "code2" text, "code3" text)       
order by t.id
```